# Почему игнорируется try/catch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5

Почему может игнорироваться блок try/catch ?

```
try
{
    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
{
    throw;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD - после ответа @aepot**

Я понимаю так, в случае исключения в `try`, должен сработать `catch` и должно продолжиться выполнение.

Но вот что то даже в обновлённом варианте тормозится всё на `try`

```
        try
        {
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Поймано исключение HttpRequestException 1");
            return (false, "");
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD - метод полностью**

```
    private async Task<(bool, string)> Sbor(string token, int poziciya)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://скрыл");

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("скрыл", "скрыл")
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        try
        {
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Поймано исключение HttpRequestException 1");
            return (false, "");
        }

        int responseHttpStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

        string otvet;
        if (responseHttpStatusCode == 200)
        {
            otvet = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return (false, "");
        }

        return (true, "скрыл");
    }
```

Comment: Task'и противная штука в плане обработки исключений. Поместите ваш try-catch блок внутрь другого Task'а. (ещё одного) Просто ради эксперимента, и попробуйте добиться появления ошибки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так у вас выброс этого исключения стоит `throw`, вот вы его и получаете. Отладчик всегда указыват не на место выброса, а на место, куда указывает стектрейс исключения.

Если написать немного по-другому

```cs
try
{
    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

То оригинальный стектрейс будет проигнорирован, вместо этого исключение будет указывать на место выброса `throw ex;`. Но так делать не принято.

Другим словами, `try-catch` работает как и должен работать в вашем случае.

Попробуйте написать свой код немного-по-другому, чтобы убедиться.

```cs
try
{
    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
catch (HttpRequestException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Поймано исключение HttpRequestException");
    throw;
}
```

Очевидно, что если вы получили вывод в консоль, то `try-catch` отработал как надо.

Так же проверьте настройки Visual Studio, возможно у вас настроен отладчик на падение при возникновении `HttpRequestException`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снимите галочку, если необходимо.

И еще здесь настройки можно проверить в меню `Tools > Options`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы как всегда стараетесь помочь, спасибо! Обновил на основе ответа, взгляните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Алексей вы смотрите не где тормозиться, а отработал ли `Debug.WritreLine`

Comment: нет, не отработал, он ничего не записал в окно вывода(

Comment: @Алексей а в параметрах отладчика стоит, что надо на этот тип исключения останавливать код? Если запускать собранное приложение без отладчика, все работает или падает?

Comment: @Алексей дополнил ответ

Comment: Настройки отладчика никогда не менял. Запустил проект с помощью Ctrl + F5 - исключение не появляется. И всё работает как надо...